# How to get Category Description in prestashop template

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I want to show a category description in my products list page (in the filters part). But I only have the name and id of the category and can't find a method in the category class that also gives me the description.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Should I need to override the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the category information with this method:

```
{assign var='cat' value=Category::getNestedCategories($categoryId)}
{$cat[categoryId].description nofilter}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code to get the category description.

```
$categories_id = Product::getProductCategories($row['id_product']);
$category = new Category($id);
$description = $category->description;
```

Comment: I need to do it inside my template. I'm on the filter (facet) part.

Answer (score 0):

Create override Link.php witj this code :

```
Class Link extends LinkCore {
    public function getInfoCateg($idc) { 
     $category = new Category($id);
     return $category->description;
    }
}
```

And in your tpl :

```
{$link->getInfoCateg($product.id_category_default)}
```

And clear cache file.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In addition to patricia, you can pass the language id, like this:

```
{assign var='cat' value=Category::getNestedCategories($categoryId,$language.id)}
{$cat[categoryId].description nofilter}
```